# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Body`. yet i already have key

Tags: reactjs

i am new to react and i have build simple value incrementing and removing project  but i got Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop error in my console. I don't know from where i am getting this error although i have already mentioned key in my div. someone please tell me from where i am getting this error

```
import React from 'react'

class Body extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
         counters:[
        {id:1, value:0},
        {id:2, value:0},
        {id:3, value:0},
        {id:4, value:0},
    ],};
   
}

render(){
    return(
        <>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="/#">Navbar
            <span className='badge badge-pill badge-secondary m-3'>{this.state.counters.filter(counter => counter.value > 0).length}</span>
            </a>
        </nav>

        <div className='container'>
            <button className='btn btn-primary btn-sm' onClick={()=>this.handleReset()}> Reset</button>
            {this.state.counters.map((counter)=>{
                return(
                    <>
                    <div key={counter.id}>
                        <span className={this.changeClass(counter)}>{counter.value ===0 ? 'zero':counter.value}</span>
                        <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={()=> this.handleIncrement(counter)} >Increment</button>
                        <button className='btn btn-danger m-2' onClick ={()=> this.handleDelete(counter)} >Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    
                    </>
                    
                )
            })}
        </div>

        </>

    )
}


changeClass(counter){
    let classes = 'btn btn-sm m-2 btn-'
    classes += counter.value === 0 ? 'warning': 'primary'
    return classes
}

handleIncrement(counter){
    
    const counters = [...this.state.counters]
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter)
    counters[index].value ++
    this.setState({counters})
   
}

handleDelete(counter){
     const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c=> c.id !== counter.id )
    this.setState({counters})
}


handleReset(){
    
   const counters = this.state.counters.map(counter=>{
        counter.value = 0
        return counter
    } )
    this.setState({counters})
      
}


 }


export default Body
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the ghost tags, they are at the highest level, so they are expected to retain the key.

if you do need the ghost tags to exist you could instead use `<React.Fragment key={...your key}>` as opposed to ghost tags

```
import React from 'react'

class Body extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
         counters:[
        {id:1, value:0},
        {id:2, value:0},
        {id:3, value:0},
        {id:4, value:0},
    ],};
   
}

render(){
    return(
        <>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="/#">Navbar
            <span className='badge badge-pill badge-secondary m-3'>{this.state.counters.filter(counter => counter.value > 0).length}</span>
            </a>
        </nav>

        <div className='container'>
            <button className='btn btn-primary btn-sm' onClick={()=>this.handleReset()}> Reset</button>
            {this.state.counters.map((counter)=>{
                return(
                    <div key={counter.id>
                    
                        <span className={this.changeClass(counter)}>{counter.value ===0 ? 'zero':counter.value}</span>
                        <button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={()=> this.handleIncrement(counter)} >Increment</button>
                        <button className='btn btn-danger m-2' onClick ={()=> this.handleDelete(counter)} >Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    
                 
                    
                )
            })}
        </div>

        </>

    )
}


changeClass(counter){
    let classes = 'btn btn-sm m-2 btn-'
    classes += counter.value === 0 ? 'warning': 'primary'
    return classes
}

handleIncrement(counter){
    
    const counters = [...this.state.counters]
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter)
    counters[index].value ++
    this.setState({counters})
   
}

handleDelete(counter){
     const counters = this.state.counters.filter(c=> c.id !== counter.id )
    this.setState({counters})
}


handleReset(){
    
   const counters = this.state.counters.map(counter=>{
        counter.value = 0
        return counter
    } )
    this.setState({counters})
      
}


 }


export default Body
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<Fragment>` or `<React.Fragment>` instead of `<>...</>` and put the `key` on that instead of the `<div>`.  It doesn't think the fragments are unique in your `map`.

Following is incorrect:

```
{myCoolArray.map(({id, data}) => (
  <> {/* Doesn't have a key */}
    <div key={id}>{data}</div> {/* Has a key */}
  </>
)}
```

Do the following instead:

```
{myCoolArray.map(({id, data}) => (
  <React.Fragment> {/* Correctly has the key */}
    <div>{data}</div> {/* Doesn't need a key */}
  </React.Fragment>
)}
```

However, if you only have 1 child, you don't actually need the fragment anyway.  You only need it when your fragment would have 2 or more sub-elements.

Answer (score 0):

remove the extra <> </> inside the map.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Array map method to display counter in UI, in your component you have to use key prop to get rid of this warning.

More: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html